# Text color will change to white or black when theme change in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-theme

In my app user can change the theme color and i want textColor to be change to black or white dynamically like if theme goes darker textColor will change to white or in light theme it will become black. 
i tried this but not work

```
Text("Name", style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.bodyText1)),
```

Comment: are you changing value of bodyText1 when user switch between themes ?

Comment: Did you create your own colors? Because flutter already does this with their ```MaterialColor``` palette unless you are overriding it with your ```TextTheme```

Comment: no i dont change bodytext1 when user swtich themes

Comment: i am using material colors

Answer (score 0):

To make sure texts are clearly legible when drawn on "primary", which is the color displayed most frequently across your app’s screens and components, you should use this color:

```
Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary
```

Similarly, you can use `onSecondary`, `onBackground`, and `onError` to produce readable texts, when texts are drawn in those situations.